# Print the contents of a list given by list containing the variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, variables

I feel like the title isn't the best so hopefully I can explain it properly.

I have a list containing the name and order of the variables needed to output.

```
outVar = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But it could contain different variables or in a different order

```
outVar = ['d', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'f']
```

The variables named in the list have values. eg:

```
a = 12
```

I want to iterate through `outVar` and print the contents of the variable. I thought I could do this like:

```
for i in range(len(outVar):
    print(outVar[i])
```

But this just prints the name of the variable. e.g. `a`, where as I want `12`.

Comment: Why are you not using a `dict`?

Comment: Please explain *why* you are doing this.  Crossing the abstraction boundary between variable names (as strings you manipulate) and their values, is a distinct "code smell" ... it almost always indicates a problem in the program design.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the scope with the function `locals()`, which will return you a `dict` containing all the local variables.

```
local_scope = locals()

for name in outVar:
    print(name, local_scope[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `dict` instead, e.g.

```py
outVar = {'a': 12, 'b': 8, ...}
```

and change your loop to

```py
for i in outVar.keys():
    print(outVar[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list you are adding the variables as character or string by using 'a'. Just remove the ' ' around the variable names in your list like: 
`outVar = [a, b, c]`

Comment: dictionary would be right solution, this solution is good till the index of all variable are fixed

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are expecting this but I will still take a stab at it

```
outVar = ['d', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'f']
d = {'a':12}
[d.get(i,i) for i in outVar]
```